# Component data is shared between multiple instances

Tags: angular, ngfor

Consider the following component:

```
  export class PropertyViewComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() property: any;
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onAddClick() {
    console.log(this.property);
  }
}
```

and the template as the following:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onAddClick()">َAdd</button>
```

The parent component template is:

```
<app-property-view *ngFor="let p of properties" [property]="p"></app-property-view>
```

When I run the app, it prints the first `property` in the `properties`! 
Is it normal?

Comment: When you say the first, do you mean he first in array?
And does in print after you click?

Comment: Could you please provide more details(code) or a StackBlitz sample for the same?

Comment: Yes, the first one in the array.

Comment: can you address clearly what problem you are facing..

Comment: you has a large number of app-property-view, each of this, has a property "property" which get the diferents values of the array "properties", the value in the position 0 for the first app-property-view, the value in position 1 for the second app-property an so on

Answer (score -1):

That was the bootstrap modal that caused the behavior.